# How to display and get data offline in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA which I already cached static files already. But I have forms (survey and application forms) which I need to display offline and user can enter data when offline then send data to the server when the user is back online, how can I go about this?. Some of my static cache code:

```
const cacheName = 'site-cache-v1';
const formCache = 'site-dynamic-cache-v1';

const urlsToCache = [
  '/',
  '/index.html  ',
  '/static/css/3.80fbce78.chunk.css ',
  '/static/css/4.3f2b4d32.chunk.css ',
  '/static/js/0.41f49890.chunk.js',
  '/static/js/10.7bd027a4.chunk.js',
  '/static/js/11.b223e049.chunk.js',
  '/static/js/12.e94b28f7.chunk.js',
  '/static/js/3.8aca5e2c.chunk.js',
  '/static/js/4.f811487f.chunk.js',
  '/static/js/5.0ee780dc.chunk.js',
  '/static/js/6.e28bc305.chunk.js',
  '/static/js/7.698a37cc.chunk.js',
  '/static/js/8.89224f2e.chunk.js',
  '/static/js/9.a4ec7686.chunk.js',
  '/static/js/main.09457d23.chunk.js',
  '/static/js/runtime~main.0a8cd6c2.js',
  '/static/media/DefaultInsightsIcon.832aa63f.png',
  '/static/media/login-bg.06aad2e4.jpg',
  '/static/media/nl-logo.10d14cfb.jpg',
  '/static/media/nl-new-logo.b4f0a2da.jpg',
];
console.log(urlsToCache);

self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  console.log('Installing…');
  // OPTION: self.skipWaiting() instead of event.waitUntil()
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName)
      .then(cache => {
        // Precaching was successful so service worker is installed.
        console.log('Opened cache');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      }, error => {
        // Precaching failed so service worker is not installed. 
        console.error(`Service Worker installation failed: ${error}`);
      })
  );
});

// Cache and return requests
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request)
          .then(cacheRes => {
            return cacheRes || fetch(event.request).then(fetchRes => {
              return caches.open(formCache).then(cache => {
                cache.put(event.request.url, fetchRes.clone());
                return fetchRes;
              })
            })
          })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then((keyList) => {
      return Promise.all(keyList.map((key) => {
        // Same cacheName that we defined before.
        if (key !== cacheName) {
          console.log('[ServiceWorker] Removing old cache', key);
          return caches.delete(key);
        }
      }));
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: Have you implemented `IndexedDB` for your PWA app? If not, you should try to explore it.

Comment: your `caches` struct persist during the user session - when the page reloads it's forgotten. So it does not make sense to cache 'css', 'js','png' - it's the task for web browser - not for your app. If you want to cache user data in forms, then as noted indexedDB or localStorage should be considered.

Answer (score 0):

The API that you'd likely want to use is [Background Sync](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync). That article includes some "vanilla" JavaScript snippets and an example app.

However, Background Sync only works in Chrome as of this writing.

If you want a solution that works across multiple browsers, [`workbox-background-sync`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-background-sync) is one option. On browsers that support Background Sync, that will be used, and in browsers that don't, it will attempt to replicate the behavior by automatically retrying queued requests each time the service worker starts up.

The library can be [used on its own](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-background-sync#advanced_usage), inside of a service worker that doesn't use other parts of [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox). (Or you can use additional parts of Workbox as well—it's up to you.)